# Having issues with uitable

Tags: matlab

I have created a uitable. In addition to that, I have a function, `f(handles, some parameters)`, that its goal is to produce a 9-by-2 matrix. Then I want to pass the matrix to the uitable. I don't want to edit it manually it just has to be edited by the function. The problem is that I can't figure out how I should pass the data to the uitable. Using `tableA_CellEditCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)` is prohibited because it doesn't accept handles. I don't know how to do that. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using set on the Data property should do the trick:

```
result = f(handles, parameters);
set(handles.uitable, 'Data', result);
```